# Adding Custom Field to Cart Page in B2B Commerce

Tags: dataextensions, custom-field, b2b-commerce, cloudcraze

I am trying extend the Cart Data Provider and I am having a bit of trouble. I need to pass a custom field to the Cart page. I am able to get custom fields to show up when I extend the Product Data Provider. Can anyone take a look at my code and let me know what it is that I am doing wrong.

This is the Product Data Provider

```
global with sharing class customServiceProduct extends ccrz.ccServiceProduct {

    global virtual override Map<String, Object> getFieldsMap(Map<String, Object> inputData) {
        inputData = super.getFieldsMap(inputData);
        String objectFields = (String)inputData.get(ccrz.ccService.OBJECTFIELDS);
        objectFields+=  ',Dwayne_Test_Field__c';

        inputData.put(ccrz.ccService.OBJECTFIELDS, objectfields);
        return inputData;
    }


}
```

This is the Cart Data Provider

```
global with sharing class ccServiceCustomCart extends ccrz.ccServiceCart {

    global virtual override Map<String, Object> getFieldsMap(Map<String, Object> inputData) {
        inputData = super.getFieldsMap(inputData);
        String objectFields = (String)inputData.get(ccrz.ccService.OBJECTFIELDS);
        objectFields+=  ',ccrz__ProductWeight__c';
        inputData.put(ccrz.ccService.OBJECTFIELDS, objectfields);
        return inputData;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need use c.customServiceProduct replace ccServiceProduct in the cc admin=>default store=> service management